# phalcon use index volt except login page

Tags: php, phalcon

I have an index volt for use every view but I want only don't use it in login page.

every volt use index volt.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        {{ get_title() }}
        {{ stylesheet_link('plugins/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
        {{ stylesheet_link('plugins/font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}
        {{ stylesheet_link('css/reset.min.css') }}
        {{ stylesheet_link('css/common.min.css') }}
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ partial('layouts/header') }}
        <div class="container">
            {{ content() }}
        </div>
        {{ partial('layouts/footer') }}
        {{ javascript_include('js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js') }}
        {{ javascript_include('plugins/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
        {{ javascript_include('plugins/sweetalert-master/dist/sweetalert.min.js') }}
    </body>
</html>
```

i don't want to use it in login page but login use it . how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

To change the layout for given page, do so in your controller:

```
$this->view->setLayout('your-custom-layout');
```

If you want to change only the template, you can use [pick](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html#picking-views):

```
$this->view->pick(['users/login']);
```

More information [about Views](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html#).

Comment: Do not forget to check your template engine configuration about folders you use: 

`$view->setViewsDir($path.'views/'); $view->setLayoutsDir('_layouts/');` More info: [Phalcon Template Documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html)